How can I get coloring as well values in a pivot in excel
I have Customer Account level data having NPS, Account Status as per Month & Year details in excel, need to make a pivot where each Account Name gives me details of Account status for each month year along with NPS data as given. Below is the example data.

Expected Result : 
How can I achieve the expected results ?

Edit your question and add example data easy to copy/paste using Tables Markdown. Also, please, post what have you tried.
